# Get ComboBoxItem from Combobox

Tags: winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

In my universal windows Application I have below "xaml" :

```
<ComboBox Margin="8" Header="Language" x:Name="cmbLanguage" x:Uid="cmbLanguage" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Languages}" SelectionChanged="LanguageComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Now i need to iterate through my combobox and get the combobox items to disable some of them. How can i get access to the items from code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now i need to iterate through my combobox and get the combobox items to disable some of them. How can i get access to the items from code behind?

You could get `ComboBoxItem` with `ContainerFromIndex` method, and the set `IsEnabled` property to false or true, for more you could refer to the follow.

```
ComboBoxItem^ item =  dynamic_cast<ComboBoxItem^>(cmbLanguage->ContainerFromIndex(CurrenIndex));
item->IsEnabled = false;
```

[image]

Comment: the item comes null always. i have 3 times added from the code behind. And can see them.

Comment: Could you show more about your "CurrenIndex" parameter?

Comment: int i = 0;
 LogMessage(cmbLanguage->Items->Size);
 for (auto item : cmbLanguage->Items)
 {
  ComboBoxItem^ item = dynamic_cast<ComboBoxItem^>(cmbLanguage->ContainerFromIndex(i));
  if (item != nullptr)
  {
   LogMessage(item->Content->ToString());
   item->IsEnabled = false;
  }
  ++i;
 }

Comment: `ComboBox` is a lazy load control, if you do not open the drop-down, 
the `ComboBoxItem` will not render. So the `item` is always empty.

Comment: That may be the reason. I will try on dropdown. actually i was testing with a button click. Let me check.

Comment: Yep, you could invoke your code in the `DropDownOpened` event handle , To make sure the ComboBoxItem  has rendered, you could make a task delay beforehand.

Comment: I am sorry. Still not working. It's getting nullptr exception.

Comment: I had no default selection. That's why it happened. After making a selection it's working.